# Heroku go buildpack : Cannot find import path for my created module

Tags: go, heroku, buildpack

I'm trying to deploy a Go web app to Heroku using [this template](https://github.com/heroku/go-getting-started) and [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go?singlepage=true). Working great locally, but when I try to deploy with

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this error:

```
remote: Parsing meta tags from https://github.com?go-get=1 (status code 200)
remote: can't load package: package github.com/f4ww4z/sipss: unknown import path "github.com/f4ww4z/sipss": cannot find module providing package github.com/f4ww4z/sipss
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to sipss.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/sipss.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sipss.git'
```

Full log after the [deployment command is here](https://pastebin.com/NUBfLyg3).

I see that heroku's actually detected the module `github.com/f4ww4z/sipss` in the `go.mod` file (see log link), so why is it throwing this `cannot find module providing package github.com/f4ww4z/sipss` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your git repo is private. Read this https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go#private-git-repos

Comment: Thanks. I also need to the 'Settings' tab and enable the go buildpack (not enabled by default).